# Get distinct values of an has_many field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model :

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :hotel_comments
end
```

In my controller, i get some hotels:

```
@hotels = Hotel.all
```

How can I get all comments for my hotel dictionary?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing what you mean by "dictionary":

```
Hash[Hotel.includes(:hotel_comments).map { |h| [h, h.hotel_comments] }]
```

If you just want all comments in a array:

```
Hotel.includes(:hotel_comments).map(&:hotel_comments).flatten(1)
```

Comment: That's what I was going to do :)

Comment: I will try that. I mean by dictionary an array of objects.

Comment: It's not good for me, I want a function on @hotels, is it possible?

Comment: @Sebastien: sure, just write a classmethod in Hotel.

Comment: @tokland It will not work because i have an Hash of Hotel and I want to get all distincts values of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your model, I am also guessing a bit here too, but how about:

```
@biglist=new(array)
@hotels.for_each do |h|
    sub_list=HotelComments.find_by_hotel_id(h.id)
    @big_list.push(sub_list)
end
```

Or, if HotelComments is large, something like:

```
@biglist=new(array)
ids=new(array)
@hotels.for_each do |h|
    ids.push(h.id)
end
@big_list=HotelComments.find_by_hotel_id(ids)
```

... would gather up the comments with one pass through HotelComments

You may find (much) better thoughts here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html